# I am trying to swap two values by pass by reference there is no error occur but the compiler throw some message

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I am trying to swap two numbers using pass by reference but it is not executing.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void swap(int,int);

    int main(){
        int x,y;
        cin>>x>>y;
        swap(x,y);
        cout<<"x= "<<x<<"y= "<<y;
        return 0;
    }

    void swap(int &x,int &y){
        int temp;
        x=temp;
        x=y;
        y=temp;
        cout<<"x= "<<x<<"y= "<<y;
    }
```

**Compiler shows this error:**

> C:\Users\amitm\AppData\Local\Temp\ccu8znRO.o:swap_reference.cpp:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `swap(int, int)' 
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You're missing the `&` signs in the declaration.

Comment: Even there is a bug in your swap function `temp` is copied to `x` before assigning any value to it

Answer (score 2):

The signature of the declaration `void swap(int,int)` is not equal to the one of the definition `void swap(int &x,int &y)`.

At the time when `swap` is called only the declaration `void swap(int,int)` is known and used, but for that declaration, there is no definition anywhere, and that's what the linker complains about:

> undefined reference to `swap(**int, int**)' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

(the **ld** in an error message tells you that it is a linker error, and linker errors indicate that you have mismatching definitions and declarations in your own code, or that you are missing a library)

You have to change the declaration to match the definition `void swap(int&,int&);`